# Cocoa: Hide other applications and self

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hide

I need a way to have an application hide itself along with all other applications. I currently have it hiding other applications, but my application stays open. I accomplished this by option-clicking my button and dragging it to the "Application" area in Utilities. Then I selected "hideOtherApplications".

Comment: You can't hide all applications. One has to be front most. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to create an application where the user clicks the "Hide All" button and all the open applications are hidden to show the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, if you just want to *show* the desktop, you can just do what you're doing and then manually order your own windows to go away. But if you want to interact with the desktop, that won't work. The desktop is part of Finder, so if you're doing things on the desktop, Finder will be the frontmost application and thus can't be hidden at that time. If you're OK with this, you can hide all applications but Finder.

But there actually is a system facility for this. Clearing all the windows so you can see the desktop is a function of Mission Control — it's listed as "Show Desktop" in the Mission Control preferences. On my system, it's F11. Unfortunately, there isn't a public API for invoking Mission Control's functions. There is a private one, though, if that's up your alley:

```
void CoreDockSendNotification(CFStringRef, void*);

void toggleShowDesktop() {
    CoreDockSendNotification(CFSTR("com.apple.showdesktop.awake"), NULL);
}
```

(With all the usual caveats that Apple do not support private APIs, will probably kick you out of the App Store if they catch you using them and don't guarantee they'll behave correctly, and this may or may not even work when Yosemite comes out because that's just kind of how private APIs are.)