# How to hide all application in mac app programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hide

In my cocoa app I want to hide all applications I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235425/cocoa-hide-other-applications-and-self) but I don't want to do in that way. so, is there any way to get result as expected.  Below code which I am using and problem is finder windows not closing.

```
 for (NSRunningApplication *app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
        [app hide];
    }
```

Comment: You can't hide all applications. One has to be front most. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Willeke I am making an app which hides the desktop Icons and In Menu bar i gave two options like where user can hide all apps and also show all hidden apps.

Comment: You can't hide the frontmost app. Which app do you want to be the fromtmost app? The default Xcode app project can Hide Others and Show All.

Comment: If i want my app to be frontmost and hide all other what to do?

Comment: Don't hide your app.

Comment: @Willeke can you help on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51946754/9551844)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178502/discussion-between-premkolindala-and-willeke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] hideOtherApplications];` call.