# How to hide other apps from a macOS menu bar app?

Tags: swift, macos

I want to be able to hide all other applications from within my macOS menu bar app. I am trying to do this with `NSWorkspace.shared.hideOtherApplications()` but it behaves erratically: sometimes all other apps are hidden, but other times one or two apps still remain visible.

I did a quick sanity check, and hiding other apps this way works perfectly on a standard (non-menu bar) SwiftUI app. So, it seems like the erratic behaviour is caused by the `Application is agent (UIElement) = YES` entry in `Info.plist`.

How can a menu bar app hide all other apps?

**Update:**

Here is how I converted my app to a menu bar app:

1. Created a new macOS project using AppKit
2. Deleted `View Controller Scene` and `Window Controller Scene` from `Main.storyboard`.
3. Deleted all menus except for the application menu
4. Set up the menu bar item using `NSMenu` and `NSStatusBar` within `AppDelegate` (`applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`)
5. Added `Application is agent (UIElement) = YES` to `Info.plist`

The app now runs in the menu bar without a dock icon.

Here is the code to create the menu bar item (from step 4):

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(
        withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    statusItem?.menu = statusMenu
    statusItem?.button?.image = NSImage(
        systemSymbolName: "b.square",
        accessibilityDescription: "")
}
```

Here is how I show my menu bar app's window and hide all other apps:

```
// Show a SwiftUI view in AppKit
let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: WindowView())
let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
let controller = NSWindowController(window: window)
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
controller.showWindow(nil)

NSWorkspace.shared.hideOtherApplications()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cocoa: Hide other applications and self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235425/cocoa-hide-other-applications-and-self)

Comment: No. The other question does not relate to a menu bar app. My problem only exists because it is a menu bar app.

Comment: You can't hide all apps, one app must be active. Which app do you want to show?

Comment: I want my app to be visible and all other apps to be hidden. Although my app lives in the menu bar, it presents a window and then tries to hide all other apps.

Comment: Is a menu bar app an app with a menu bar? Can you manually hide all other apps?

Comment: A menu bar app cannot hide all all apps other than itself, window or not.

Comment: @Willeke The menu bar app lives in the top right menu and has no dock icon -- like Spotlight. I can manually hide the other apps, except the last one. It seems like menu bar apps don't count towards "visible apps", even if they have visible windows. Though, it doesn't explain why sometimes there are more than one app visible after hiding the others. In those cases, I can manually hide the remaining visible apps up until the last visible app.

Comment: @matt `hideOtherApplications()` does have an effect, just not the desired one. So, it seems like menu bar apps can hide other apps, but not all of them reliably. Can you point to any docs or references on this? Better still, a suggested workaround?

Comment: When your app isn't the active app (it can't be if it is a status item and doesn't have a menu bar) and hides the active app then another app becomes active. Activating takes some time and things can get out of sync. Have you tried hiding all `NSRunningApplication`s except the active one?